# If I call `writev` on a socket, is the full response created in memory, or only in the client?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming, client-server

Suppose I'm connected to a client over a TCP socket, and I call `writev` on the socket with 3 items, saying "write 16 bytes from address A, 32 bytes from address B, and 16 more from address A again."

Would the full, 64-byte message be assembled in the memory of my machine, or would each item in the vector be sent, acked, and forgotten on the server separately, such that the complete message is only assembled on the other end of the socket?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Thanks for your help! I'm not doing this directly; I'm using the Erlang web server Cowboy. A dtrace script shows me that it's using `writev` to send the responses (which are a list of strings the last time I see them), but I haven't dug deeper than that. I'm just intrigued by the idea that maybe the complete web response is only built in the client's browser. I was hoping there would be a simple answer. :D

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful No. `writev()` is a BSD Sockets system call, and `BufferedWriter` has precisely nothing to do with it. The messages will not be 'sent, acknowledged, and then forgotten, in order individually'.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful You can disagree as much as you like but the vector elements are not sent or acknowledged individually; there is nothing in the documentation that says otherwise; and you can't interpose a buffered stream between a system call and the system. I haven't said anything that would imply an ordering violation, and I do not understand why you even raise the topic. I frankly don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Please stop this. I misinterpreted nothing. Any misinterpretation is yours alone. The question is about `writev()`, and anything you've said that doesn't apply to it, which appears to be everything, is therefore irrelevant. You've also made an incorrect statement about messages and acknowledgements, beyond what you now admit to, and you've falsely accused me of somehow neglecting ordering when I haven't said anything incorrect about it. I have no idea what Erlang has to do with it and I don't care to find out.  Would you now please stop wasting other people's time.

Comment: @ejp It appears that the other person in this comment thread has deleted his/her comments. Would you mind deleting your responses? I'll delete this also afterward to clean up this Q&A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would the full, 64-byte message be assembled in the memory of my machine, or would each item in the vector be sent, acked, and forgotten on the server separately, such that the complete message is only assembled on the other end of the socket?

`writev()` collects the data from the vector and copies it to the socket send buffer. If you're in blocking mode it blocks while the socket send buffer is full. Once in the socket send buffer, the data is sent any way that TCP likes. It might well be in one TCP segment, or it could be as bad as one byte at a time. There is no necessary correlation whatever with the elements of the original vector.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful The OP didn't ask about byte ordering. It was you that introduced the topic, for reasons which I cannot fathom.

Comment: Thanks for de-confusing me. :) Some [docs on writev](http://linux.die.net/man/2/writev) say it's atomic and the data is written as a single block, so clearly the full message would exist, at least momentarily, in the send buffer.

Comment: @NathanLong Only if it fits.